# Remove classes from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get content from an input and store it in a var called 'content'

I then need to manipulate this var and remove classes from any img tags. I've tried:

```
$('img', content).removeClass('c1 c2');
```

But with no luck.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is the relation between `img` and `var content`?

Comment: There are img tags inside the content

Comment: what you want to manipulate in the `var content` and on what condition you want to remove the classes from `img`

Comment: I want to remove the classes from every img tag

Comment: `$('<div />').html( $.parseHTML(content) ).find('img').removeClass().html()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can create a virtual div to hold the `content` as its html, then you can remove the classes. like:

```js
var content = '<div><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/128/Money.png" class="c1 c2" ></div>';
var vdiv = $('<div>', {
  html: content
}); // <----hold the content

vdiv.find('img').removeClass('c1 c2'); // <--find img and remove the classes

$(document.body).append(vdiv.find('img')); // <----now you can log it out to see.
```

```css
img{box-shadow:22px 22px 10px #ccc;}
.c1{background:blue;}
.c2{padding:10px; border:solid 10px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code snippet below is the opposite  upper code execution to let you see if you comment out `removeClass` line the what is the output.

```js
var content = '<div><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-business-desktop-icons/128/Money.png" class="c1 c2" ></div>';
var vdiv = $('<div>', {
  html: content
}); // <----hold the content

// vdiv.find('img').removeClass('c1 c2'); // <--find img and remove the classes

$(document.body).append(vdiv.find('img')); // <----now you can log it out to see.
```

```css
img{box-shadow:22px 22px 10px #ccc;}
.c1{background:blue;}
.c2{padding:10px; border:solid 10px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solution could help:

```js
// String images tags
var imgs = '<img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" class="c1 c2"/> text ' +
           '<img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" class="c1"/> more text ' +
           '<img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" class="c2"/>';

// Put the string on input
$("input[type=text]").val(imgs);

// Get val of input (its the same that get string of images tags)
var content = $("input[type=text]").val();

// Convert content to jquery object
var $htmlContent = $(content);

// evaluate all img items and remove c1 and c2 class 
$htmlContent.each(function (index) {
  if ($(this).is('img')) $(this).removeClass('c1 c2');
});

// insert content
$htmlContent.insertAfter("input[type=text]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make jQuery object from content, find all img tags within it and remove the classes from each img tag:

```
$(content).find('img').removeClass('c1 c2')
```